# Lorem Ipsum placeholder Images

Tags: website-design, resource-recommendations, website-templates, placeholder

What are the placeholder or filler images that are constantly used longside Lorem Ipsum text? I have seen these images in the Google Docs templates and would like to know where I can find these images for my website layouts.

Comment: Do you mean placeholder images that are used alongside Lorem ipsum, or images *of* Lorem ipsum? I initially though the latter but the former would make more sense. (Could you maybe include an example too?)

Comment: @Cai Yes, I mean images that are used alongside Lorem Ipsum.

Comment: For what it's worth, I use *Star Trek* imagery whenever I can get away with it. All the clients recognize it and no one is ever going to assume it's live material. (Plus nobody actually wants images of me all over their website!)

Answer (score 6):

There are several placeholder image sites.

- [placekitten.com](http://placekitten.com) (kitten placeholders)
- [placebear.com](http://placebear.com) (bear placeholders)
- [fillmurray.com](http://fillmurray.com) (Bill Murray placeholders)
- [placecage.com](http://placecage.com) (Nicolas Cage placeholders)
- [dummyimage.com](http://dummyimage.com) (just blank image with dimensions)

There are more.. just Google search for "placeholder images".

Comment: The doggy site has being terminated... Hasta la vista, baby.

Comment: Removed then :) I tend to stick with placekitten or dummyimage

Answer (score 4):

If you only want place holder images, just use some Creative Commons images. Do a search at the Creative Commons search website. search(dot)creativecommons(dot)org

Alternatively, many stock photography sites let you download watermarked images for free - such as istockphoto(dot)com

In istockphoto just find the image you want, click on it to open the photo page, then click on the image to enlarge, then right click the image and choose view image, and copy it and paste it into your document.  Obviously, if you want to use the images, ultimately you'll need to buy a licence to get the unwatermarked image.

Comment: For in-house use only, I tend to amuse myself using silly images.  For example, I frequently include headshots within my documents, but may not have a headshot from each person yet.  So, I have found a number of Creative Commons licensed images that can be stand-ins for headshots, and that make me laugh (here's an example: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/Dogs_like_cucumbers_%26_cucumbers_like_dogs.jpg), and I will use those as placeholders.  The rest of my team has started calling boilerplate text that still needs editing "dog with cucumber" text.

Answer (score 2):

@Metis provides a great batch, including some I hadn't seen before, but just wanted to add that for those of us with less humorous clients watching end work coming together on staging sites that these:

- https://placehold.it/ (Totally boring)
- http://lorempixel.com/ (Quite boring)

...are more sober (boring) ;)